# phpbb3 email settings for Zoho SMTP server

Tags: email, bulk-email, phpbb, smtp

I've spent a while guessing and googling, and haven't found an answer.  In the past I setup my forums to send via my Gmail account, but spambots with fake emails have flooded my inbox, so I setup noreply@domain.net with Zoho mail.  Zoho works great, but I need to have my installation of phpbb3 send mass emails through the smtp.zoho.com mail server, and I can't figure out what settings I should use.  The instructions on https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/pop-access.html are a little vague for anything that doesn't auto-detect the exact settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STEP 1. Check your host can send SMTP mail over SSL

To send emails using ZOHO your web host must have enabled SASLv2 and STARTTLS installed, you may need to contact your web server host to double check.

STEP 2. [Enabling POP3](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/pop-access.html#EnablePOPAccess)

> You need to enable POP access of the Zoho Mail account, to start
>   accessing the account in other POP clients. You can enable POP access
>   for all emails from the beginning or from the particular day.
>
> - Log in to https:\www.zoho.com\mail
> - Click Settings >> Mail >> Email Forwarding POP and IMAP.
> - Under POP Access select one of the options below
>
>   - Enable - Enable POP access for all emails in the account.
>   - Enable from now on – Enable POP access for emails that arrive from the time the user enables POP access.
> - Click Save for the changes to be effective.

STEP 3. Adding the details to PHPBB3

- Use SMTP server for e-mail: Yes
- SMTP server address: ssl://smtp.zoho.com
- SMTP server port: 465
- Authentication method for SMTP: LOGIN
- SMTP username: Your Username
- SMTP password: Your Password

STEP 4 (Optional). Finding Errors

If any any point you get stuck you should seek help from the error log, normally found in  `Admin Control Panel > Maintenance tab > Error log`.

Comment: E-mail error
» EMAIL/SMTP
/forum/ucp.php

Could not get mail server response codes.
Backtrace

Connecting to ssl://smtp.zoho.com:465
LINE: 1047 <- 220 mx.zohomail.com SMTP Server ready May 31, 2014 1:37:24 PM PDT

# EHLO ex-std-node298.prod.rhcloud.com
LINE: 1319 <- 250-mx.zohomail.com Hello ex-std-node298.prod.rhcloud.com (ec2-174-129-158-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com (174.129.158.197))

LINE: 1319 <- 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN

LINE: 1319 <- 250 SIZE 25000000

# AUTH PLAIN
LINE: 1427 <- 334

Comment: and have you contacted you website host to ask if they support SSL sending?

Comment: They do.  I found the correct settings by tweaking the ones you gave, and I submitted an edit.